# How can I centralize business rules between SQL queries and application logic (ColdFusion 8)?

Tags: oop, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, business-rules

I've slowly but surely been re-factoring one of my client's websites to improve the overall business logic and avoid duplicate code. One of the primary areas I've been working on is the products in a basic shopping cart application:

1. Item Search, using SQL queries against the database
2. Product Detail template
3. View Cart
4. Checkout (Enter Address, Confirm Order, Submit)

There are many business rules around the products, for instance:

- which products are view-able
- which products are view-able to certain users
- which products are order-able
- which formats each product can be ordered in
- etc.

For years, all of these rules were duplicated throughout the website - some in SQL queries, some in application logic, some in both - and the way they were implemented was different on some pages. In fact, some of the rules were not implemented on certain pages (not by design).

New sub-applications have been created as well, which have different rules.

So, wherever a product is displayed, I have implemented the use of a "Product" class, which contains all of the business rules in the application logic (i.e. Product.isViewable(), Product.isOrderable(), etc.).

This allows the Product data to be used in each of the sub-applications with the that application's specific rules by extending the Product class.

The only problem I currently have is the Item Search page, which queries the database and includes many of the "old" business rules, using a combination of ColdFusion application logic (if/else, etc.) and SQL conditions. Here's s snippet of the SQL query:

```
            WHERE   (
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(UCASE(STATUS))) = 'ACTIVE'
                    OR UCASE(VIEWABLE_IF_RETIRED_FLAG) = 'Y'
                    )
            <cfif SESSION.User.getSecurityLevel() LT 5>
                AND (
                    UCASE(ORDERABLE_FLAG) = 'Y'
                    OR UCASE(ELECTRONIC_ORDERABLE_FLAG) = 'O'
                    OR UCASE(ELECTRONIC_ORDERABLE_FLAG) = 'V'
                    )
            </cfif>
```

These same rules are implemented in the Product class:

```
    function isVisibleIfRetired() {
        return getVisibleIfRetiredFlag() == "Y";
    }

    function isActive() {
        return getStatus() == "ACTIVE";
    }

    function isDigitalViewable() {
        return  UCase(getIsProductOrderableFlag()) == "Y"
            &&  (
                    UCase(getElectronicOrderableStatus()) == "V"
                ||  UCase(getElectronicOrderableStatus()) == "O"
                );
    }
```

This drives me crazy, because it is still essentially duplicate code, and both pieces need to be managed, should a business rule change.

There are some place where I display only a few items (a "similar items" widget, for example, as well as "View Cart"), and I can simply select the Product Key from the database, and then loop over those values to create Product instances and use the business rules in the class to determine if/how to display the product.

However, the item search query can return up to 2000 records, and I can't [realistically] loop over 2000 records creating a 2000 instances to determine display based on business rules.

Any ideas?

Comment: My suggestion is to implement as many rules as possible in your database design.

Comment: Move away from SQL stored in the code, and go to stored procedures.  It helps alot when handling what should be database side items.

Comment: @Limey I'm limited in this respect, as we only have one database developer in our team, and he is already overloaded with higher priority tasks. Plus that still doesn't solve the problem I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this:  What if you were to create a rule interface.  IE a set of CFCs that described rules.  If they all implemented the same interface (either explicitly or through duck typing) then you could decorate your data access objects and in other classes such as your Product class.

The API for these rules could be something like (in pseudo code):

```
component name="product is visible"{

    function ruleAsSqlFragment(){
        // return a chunk of SQL here that you can drop right into your query and would cause the query to be filtered as you wish.
        return "LTRIM(RTRIM(UCASE(STATUS))) = 'ACTIVE'
                OR UCASE(VIEWABLE_IF_RETIRED_FLAG) = 'Y'";
    }

    function validateRule(object){
        // this function might accept an object, validate it according to its rules and return true or false
        return object.isActive() or object.getViewableIfRetired()
    }

}
```

You could then make an array of these rules which you decorate your objects with:

```
rules = [isVisibleRule,isSomethingElseRule,etc];
```

Inside your objects you could simply loop over the array and call the appropriate function to evaluate the rule or generate the correct SQL fragment.  The rule is only satisfied if the function or SQL syntax evaluate to true.

Overall, I'm not sure that using traditional approaches to SQL that you can completely avoid duplicate business logic.  They're both (SQL and CF) different languages after all.

I suppose another option would be to define a domain specific language (DSL) and use that to define your rules.  And then write a component that can translate those rules into SQL or evaluate them against an object.  Then find a way to associate specific rules defined in your DSL into your components in the correct manner and evaluate them as needed.

Another challenge is that it looks like your database doesn't completely mirror your object model, which is pretty typical.  If this is the case them I'm pretty sure you'll just have to try to isolate this logic to the greatest degree possible.

Answer (score 1):

Start with automated tests (unit tests, for example) for these business rules. The tests will suggest an object model, if you listen to them (by ignoring your current implementation when you write the tests, for example).

You will likely find a few (maybe several) CFCs that you wished existed to implement those business rules. Write your tests as if they existed.

Each rule should have a canonical implementation. That is to say that if your rule determines which products are view-able then one CFC method should determine that. That method may internally use CFML, SQL, calls to other CFC methods, whatever. The point is that everything that needs to use that rule will call that method to do it. Your tests test that method to see if the rule is being correctly followed.

If you haven't started writing automated tests, check out MXUnit and do a bit of reading on TDD or BDD.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development